# PySpark: How to use/tune garbage collector?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There are many examples on how to tune garbage collector in Java. It's usually done by passing command, e.g. `-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC`. How one tunes GC in PySpark?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with [spark-dataframe](/questions/tagged/spark-dataframe) the answer is pretty simple - there should be no need for garbage collection tuning, and even if there was, you'd typically use Java GC options.

To understand why:

- Spark `DataFrame` is primarily a Java object with Python wrappers present only on the driver - data and SQL operations don't really hit Python interpreter, with exception of user defined functions.
- Spark SQL depends heavily on native off-heap memory so GC tuning impact should be negligible. On heap memory is used mainly with Spark MLlib - if your code depends on ML features use standard JVM GC options.
- Even if your code uses Python udfs, GC tuning might be required only if you use non standard interpreter implementation (other than CPython). With CPython primary garbage collection method is reference counting, which doesn't require any tuning. Fully GC cycle is required only in presence of cyclical reference which are unlikely to occur in udf.

Comment: In that case, I should mention that there's one step where DataFrame is converted to RDD for ease with matrix multiplication and then converted back to DF. Not sure if that's the biggest issue, but I'm observing about 70% of the time to be spent on GC. How can I pass GC/java parameters to `submit-spark` cmd? With `--conf`?

Comment: With [`spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning). Python GC is not reflected in the UI so what is JVM GC time. Probably with all the temporary objects required for conversion (and possibly shuffle during multiplication).

Comment: If you update your answer to directly include reference to that config then I'm happy to accept this as answer. However, you mentioned about shuffling and cleaning after multiplication. Any references for this? I created 20000x300 np.array which is broadcasted and multiplice each row. Could this be the issue?